# Django-Crispy Forms embed a Django-Tables2 table in a Tab Layout

Tags: django-crispy-forms, django-tables2

Using Crispy forms I have tried to embed the render inside an HTML block.

```
 HTML("{% render_table events %}"),
```

I went to the Crispy Template Pack and I added this to the top of every bootstrap html template

```
  {% load render_table from django_tables2 %}
```

but still get this:

```
Invalid block tag on line 1: 'render_table'. Did you forget to register or load this tag?
1   {% render_table events %}
```

Comment: Did you manage to solve it ?

Answer (score 3):

You have to load the `django-tables2` template tag library:

```
HTML("{% load django_tables2 %}{% render_table events %}")
```

Comment: This worked 100% I had tried this which still fails. So I was close FWIW HTML("{% load render_table from django_tables2 %}"),
                                        HTML("{% render_table events %}"),  # can't render

Comment: Not sure what you mean by this, but I guess every call to HTML has a new template context so needs to load the template tags again.

Comment: That is basically what I deduced AFTER your post..point is it doesn't work when you separate them..

Comment: How to pass events to crispy form or passing it from view while rendering the view will do the trick? In my case I am passing it to template along with the form & hoping when template is getting rendered with crispy form it will get the event, but its not working. It gives error saying "Expected table or queryset, not str".